# How i can check group of number like this in JavaScript Regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match group of 10 numbers `1` or `mores` times (it should separate by `,` if more than one group).

```
pattern: 0123456789,9876543210,...
```

AND each group must start with `00`

```
pattern: 0023456789,0076543210,00...
```

I try to do like this and stuck:

```
/(?:\d{10}(?:,(?!$)|$)){1,}/.test('1111111111')
```

There are patterns i want to:

```
/pattern/.test('0012345678') // should true
/pattern/.test('0012345678,0012345678') // should true
```

Comment: Why regex? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I don't see the pattern that you are after, but anyway, this website may be useful to you: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that will do this.

```
/^00[0-9]{8}(,00[0-9]{8})*$/
```

Comment: should not true - /00[0-9]{8}(,00[0-9]{8})+/.test('0012345678,001234567890') and more fails

Comment: Also that example should fail -- each group is not of length 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp `/^(00\d{8})(?:,(00\d{8}))*$/` to match a group of 10 numbers 1 or more times.

```js
const pattern = /^(00\d{8})(?:,(00\d{8}))*$/
console.log(pattern.test('0123456789')) //should false
console.log(pattern.test('0123456789,9876543210')) //should false
console.log(pattern.test('0023456789')) //should true
console.log(pattern.test('0023456789,0076543210')) //should true
console.log(pattern.test('0023456789,0076543210,0123456789')) //should false
console.log(pattern.test('00123456789999999')) //should false
console.log(pattern.test('00123456789999999,0023456789')) //should false
console.log(pattern.test('0023456789,00123456789999999')) //should false
```

Comment: /(00[0-9]{8}),?/.test('00123456789999999') // should false but true

Comment: Great thanks @ParthoShuvo but i can accept only one answer!

Comment: `/^((00[0-9]{8}),?)+$/.test('00234567890023456789')` should be false but it's true

Comment: See the latest change.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex but it works perfectly!

```js
console.log(check('0012345678'));
console.log(check('0012345678,0012345678'));
console.log(check('hi'));
console.log(check('00hello123,0011111111'));
console.log(check());
console.log(check(''));
console.log(check('0000000000'));
/* expected output:

   true
   true
   false
   false
   false
   false
   true
*/

function check(numbers) {
  if (numbers === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  numbers = String(numbers);
  if (numbers == '') {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i of numbers.split(',')) {
    if (i.length != 10) { // length must be 10
      return false;
    }
    if (i.replace(/[0-9]*/, '') != '') { // contains only numbers
      return false;
    }
    if (!i.startsWith('00')) { // starts with "00"
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```